# How to make the review field optional in OC 3.x?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

[image]

I need the name and the rating fields to be required and the review field to be optional. I'm using OC 3.x with Journal theme, it is possible from the panel or should I modify the MVC arhitecture to achieve this? Some users told me that they want to rate but without typing any text/review. I'm thinking if I modify the form group from required to optional from the view, it will give an error because the database will expect also the review. So there is any way from the admin panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not be able to do this through the admin panel.
But you can do it like this:
Remove condition from controller `catalog/controller/product/product.php` in method `write()`

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) > 1000)) {
  $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
}
```

You don't need to do anything in the database because this field is optional in the schema.

Comment: Fair enough, I commented that lines from the controller and I removed from catalog/view/theme/journal3/template/product/product.twig, {% if option.required %} required {% endif %} from option.type text and textarea, inside the form group. But I still receive the error message when I try to give a rate with empty review field that it needs to be between x and y characters.

Comment: Did you remove the check from the controller?

Comment: I have changed my answer. There is no validation in the template. There is nothing to do there. You just need to remove the validation in the controller as mentioned in the answer, please give it a try)

Comment: Yes, but I still get the error that the review must be between x and y characters.

Comment: It's strange, if you removed the check from the coroller, then most likely it was preserved in the modifiers. Try to clean them up.

Comment: So I removed the check, clean the cache and the browser as well, but it still appears.

Comment: I had to clean and refresh the cache from OCMOD, dunno why, but now it is working. Thanks.